# launch an activity every time the device is unlocked on android oreo

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am currently working on an app to launch an activity every time the device is unlocked, the following code works well for smaller devices with the Android api oreo.

Manifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".ScreenReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" >
            </category>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I also have in the manifest

```
 <uses-permission android: name ="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

ScreenReceiver class:

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
ScreenReceiver screen;
Context context=null;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    this.context=context;
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)||intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)||intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT))
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, DictionaryView.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

}

I need to launch an activity every time the phone is unlock the previous code works pretty well for earlier versions of Android Oreo, but this version does not work because it never starts the activity after unlocking the device.
Friends please I need help takes a couple of hours looking for useful information without success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Broadcast Receiver on Android Oreo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798985/broadcast-receiver-on-android-oreo)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to ask for permission from the user

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED)  != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            )
    {
        //REQUEST RUNTIME PERMISSION
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {
                android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED,                    
        }  ,    MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

Then you will have to setup an overrride method to handle on requestpermissionresult

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
               //do this
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETE` is not a runtime permission, as per the [list of dangerous permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#permission-groups)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Your code look like this:**

```
<receiver android:name=".ScreenReceiver"
    android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" >
        </category>
    </intent-filter>
```

**Please remove all tag in intent filter code look like this**

```
<receiver android:name=".ScreenReceiver>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

**ScreenReceiver class:**

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
ScreenReceiver screen;
Context context=null;
   @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, DictionaryView.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
}
```

try this i hope it helps you.

Comment: Gracias por SU respuesta pero su código no trabaja para mi, como mencione arriba mi código no funciona para Android Oreo.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but your code does not work for me, as mentioned above my Code does not work for Android Oreo.