# Broadcast receiver is not working in oreo and pie android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo, android-9.0-pie

Boot broadcast receiver is not working and there is nothing in onReceive()

```
public class BootReceived extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Toast.makeText(context, intent.getAction(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.d("IfWalaBooot", intent.getAction());

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent1);

        Intent tni = new Intent(context, MainService.class);
        tni.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startService(tni);

    }
```

}

Comment: Did you register in manifest

Comment: @Pooja when you say that bootreceiver is not working, does it mean [1] you are getting boot complete even but not able to start service or [2] you are not getting boot complete event?  From Android-O onward there is restriction on implicit broadcasts.   https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#android_80

Comment: @Manoj Perumarath i have registered in manifest as well as in main activity also but nothing is trigger

Comment: @Ranjan Kumar i am not getting boot complete event

Comment: You need to register it in onStart and unregister it in onDestroy.

Comment: @Tushar onStart..?

Comment: Yes! so when the activity is visible to the user, you will get the broadcast events

Comment: @Tushar what if app is in background?

Comment: Why do you need to run it in the background? If you want to run something in the background, use Services/ Job Scheduler/ Work Managers instead.

Comment: Broadcast receivers reacts to system events.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html

Comment: This may help you https://medium.com/@berriz_/service-and-boot-completed-on-android-o-6a389eae50f1

Comment: @Tushar can you please give an example for boot event? whatever it is service/job scheduler/work manager Please

Comment: https://medium.com/@berriz_/service-and-boot-completed-on-android-o-6a389eae50f1

Comment: @Tushar above example is not working for me

Comment: Pooja,  share your AndroidManifests.xml file

Comment: Please add your manifest to the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798985/broadcast-receiver-on-android-oreo

Comment: you can try this https://github.com/devggaurav/BroadcastReceiver-For-Naught-and-Oreo-devices

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that you have registered your receiver in Manifest .
2. [Implicit Broadcast Exceptions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions) refer to this link to check if your implicit receiver 
   is in exception list or not.
3. if not in exception the you can make job scheduler or register your receiver in your code itself .Here is a nice snippet you could refer on [It’s time to kiss goodbye to your implicit BroadcastReceivers](https://medium.com/@iiro.krankka/its-time-to-kiss-goodbye-to-your-implicit-broadcastreceivers-eefafd9f4f8a)