# Broadcast receiver is not working only when app is closed in android pie

Tags: android, background, broadcastreceiver

I am using `Broadcast Receiver` to trigger for `incoming messages` every time. Its working fine in `Android O` either app is closed or not. But in `Android P` its only working when app is live and when app is closed its not working. It should always work either app is close or not in `Android P`. I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55429554/broadcast-receiver-is-not-working-in-oreo-and-pie-android) and many others but problem is still there.

**Receiver Registration in Manifest**

```
<receiver
            android:name=".Broadcast.SmsListener"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

**Broadcast Receiver Class**

```
    public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Resulted12", "Into onReceive()");
        context.startService(new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class));
    }
}
```

Is there anything else which i missed?

Comment: 1. My app is not default.
2. I'm doing something from where I can determine either BR is triggering or not.
3. Yes I tested it both emulator and real devices.

on android O its wroking fine but not in android p.

Comment: After removing SMS_DELIVER <action>, BR will always trigger when new message will arrive in Android P either app is in running form or not.

Comment: I am asking a question.

Comment: Can you tell what the issue is?
What changes should I do?

Comment: @Mike M I edited the question. Now you can see what I want to do by triggering BR.

Comment: Service is working fine in Android O.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After spending few days I found the real issue.

My code was **working fine** on **Android O** and **Android P** both in **foreground** and **background** but when I clear the app from the recent apps list, it stops working on some devices because of

**Manufacturers have added task manager feature by default which force stops the apps for memory/battery management. But few applications like Whatsapp, Facebook works. This can be because they would have whitelisted the most famous applications.**

For more information follow the below link

**[clear Recent apps wipe the apps memory and my receiver stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41277671/clear-recent-apps-wipe-the-apps-memory-and-my-receiver-stopped-working/41369032)**

Answer (score 0):

From Android **O** Manufacturers  set Battery optimization which can prevent Broadcast receiver from calling when app is removed from Background. So you can put popup which is redirect to app battery optimize setting and user can toggle to don't optimize option if they want to run app in background.
Here I have implemented Battery Optimization for different Manufacturers  .

In Manifest add permission of:
`android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"`

```
private fun checkAndAskForBatteryOptimization() {
  
try {


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28) {

            val powerManager = this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
            if (!powerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(getPackageName())) {


                val intent = Intent()
                intent.action = "android.settings.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"
                if (Build.MANUFACTURER.toUpperCase() == "VIVO") {
                    startActivityForResult(Intent("android.settings.SETTINGS"), 50)
                    headsUpNotification()
                } else if (Build.MANUFACTURER.toUpperCase() == "OPPO" || Build.MANUFACTURER.toUpperCase() == "REALME") {
                    val intent3 = Intent("android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS")
                    intent3.data = Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null as String?)
                    startActivityForResult(intent3, 50)
                    headsUpNotification()
                } else if (Build.MANUFACTURER.toUpperCase() == "XIAOMI") {
                    intent.action = "android.settings.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"
                    intent.data = Uri.parse("package:" + packageName)
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 50)
                    headsUpNotification()
                } else if (Build.MANUFACTURER.toUpperCase().contains("ONEPLUS")) {
                    val intent4 = Intent("android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS")
                    intent4.data = Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null as String?)
                    startActivityForResult(intent4, 50)
                    headsUpNotification()
                } else if (Build.MANUFACTURER.toUpperCase().contains("SAMSUNG")) {

                } else {
                    intent.data = Uri.parse("package:" + packageName)
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 50)
                }
            } else {

            }
        } else {

        }
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {

    }
}
```