# Broadcast receiver not listening on Oreo when app gets killed

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

my broadcast receiver is working fine on Pause() function but when i kill my app my broadcast receiver stops listening only in oreo but working fine on other API Levels less then oreo. i also registered my broadcast receiver in my manifest file and also registered it on my resume().

My Main Activity Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startService(new Intent(this, BroadcastService.class));
    Log.i(TAG, "Started service");
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(BroadcastService.COUNTDOWN_BR));
    Log.i(TAG, "Registered broacast receiver");
}
```

Here is my Service class:

```
public class BroadcastService  extends Service {

    private final static String TAG = "BroadcastService";

    public static final String COUNTDOWN_BR = "com.codecollapse";
      Intent bi = new Intent(COUNTDOWN_BR);

    CountDownTimer cdt = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Log.i(TAG, "Starting timer...");

        cdt = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                Log.i(TAG, "Countdown seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                bi.putExtra("countdown", millisUntilFinished);
                //sendBroadcast(bi);
                sendBroadcast(new Intent(getBaseContext(), CountDownReceiver.class).setAction("com.codecollapse").putExtra("countdown",millisUntilFinished));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                bi.putExtra("IsFinish",true);
                Log.i(TAG, "Timer finished");
            }
        };

        cdt.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        cdt.cancel();
        Log.i(TAG, "Timer cancelled");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is my receiver class

```
public class CountDownReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "You Poke the service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.androidservices">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name=".CountDownReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.codecollapse"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".BroadcastService" />
</application>
```

Comment: I would highly suggest looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798985/broadcast-receiver-on-android-oreo).

Comment: @tomerpacific i have did this on my resume function but it is not working only on oreo u can check in my code

Comment: I don't see where you are unregistering your receiver and I don't understand why you are registering it on onResume. Why not in onCreate? And since your broadcast receiver is explicit, as it is targeting only your application, it should not be of an issue.

Comment: i am not unregistering my receiver because when my app gets killed then my receiver will not work that is why i use explicit broadcast reciever

Comment: also it is not working on onCreate method

Comment: Service has been stopped to run in background since oreo onward. So the issue may coming. You create an another sample app and send the broadcast from there, it should work.

Comment: @HariNJha did this but not working

Comment: Please check my posted answer and follow that. If you have maintained the flow like wise and getting the issue then I think you should check the issue related to JobScheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can read the topic as announced with Oreo 8.0 release:

[image]

you can see the detail of it at [official link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background).